# Integration/Widget test using Stacked Architecture by FilledStacks which is based od get_it

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, integration-testing, stacked

In my project I use Stacked Architecture with [Inversion of Control](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/flutter-and-provider-architecture-using-stacked/#inversion-of-control). In Unit Testing it works perfectly fine but when it comes to Widget/Integration Testing I am getting an error right at the start.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:my_project/ui/start_up/startup_viewmodel.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets(
    "Simple widget test",
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(StartUpView());
    },
  );
}
```

The error that I get:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building StartUpView:
Object/factory with  type AuthService is not registered inside GetIt.
(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)
'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart':
Failed assertion: line 372 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != null'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  StartUpView
  StartUpView:file:path/my_project/lib/app/app.router.dart:87:37
```

From the error log I see that it is actually the **AuthService** which is causing the problem. The class is registered as a **LazySingleton** in *app.dart* and I realized that the program really crashes in *startup_viewmodel.dart*:

```
  final _authService = locator<AuthService>();
  final _navigationService = locator<NavigationService>();
```

(Switching this to lines cause to replace **AuthService** with **NavigationService** in error message).

Suggestions about *get_it* didn't help me much because in all of the files "get_it" didn't comes once (even in my *pubspec.yaml*). I also tried solutions from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548585/how-to-use-get-it-flutter-dependency-injection-in-the-widget-test) but it didn't resolve the issue.

The *app.router.dart* is a generated code based on *app.dart*. In its 87. line there is:

```
    StartUpView: (data) {
      return MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
        builder: (context) => const StartUpView(),
        settings: data,
      );
    },
```

Lastly I tried using *integration_test_driver* and running test through *flutter test* command with no improvement.

So the simple question is...

### How to Widget Test using Stacked Architecture?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My answer might be too late, but for anyone finding this question in the future the answer is that you have to register all the required services before running the tests. Based on how this question is asked, I assume that the [Guide To Unit Testing](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/practical-guide-to-unit-testing-in-flutter/) by the developer of stacked has been followed.

In that case the only thing that has to be done is to add the following in either `main` or a `group` depending on which tests need the services:

```
setUp(() => registerServices());
tearDown(() => unregisterService());
```